# Python Meta Class Inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, factory-boy

### What am I trying to do?

I am trying to create a base factory boy class with the class meta set as follows:

```
class DBFactoryBase(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        sqlalchemy_session = common_session
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = 'flush'
```

I then want to inherit from this and use it in my factories instead of factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory:

```
class SomeFactory(DBFactoryBase):

    class Meta:
        model = AnSQLAlchemyModel

    fake_line_1 = "A'tuin"
    fake_line_2 = 'The currently untitled'
    fake_line_3 = '42'
```

Essentially I want to be able to extend the class Meta instead of overriding it and by updating the base model session I want the other models to inherit that session.

### Why am I trying to do this?

I am doing this for convenience, so I don't have to redefine these with all of my factory classes. I am also doing it so that I can override the session whilst running pytest using the below fixture. I don't want my factories defined inside fixtures because I also want to use the same factories to create demo data. Thus I need to pass them a none-test DB session and making the factories as fixtures will stop me from using them in regular scripts.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def test_db(engine_factory, enable_override):
    engine = engine_factory
    testing_session_local = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    api.dependency_overrides[get_db] = enable_override
    session: Session = testing_session_local()

    DBFactoryBase.sqlalchemy_session = session # <-- Please see here

    yield session
    # Rollback the session => no changes to the database
    session.rollback()
    # Remove it, so that the next test gets a new Session()
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
```

If this were a Django-based Model I could access the parent's class meta as an attribute using DBFactoryBase.Meta and pass this into the class meta like below. I am not entirely sure how this works neither do I know how to do this when the original class is not a Django Model.

```
class SomeFactory(DBFactoryBase):

    class Meta(DBFactoryBase.Meta):
        model = AnSQLAlchemyModel

    fake_line_1 = "A'tuin"
    fake_line_2 = 'The currently untitled'
    fake_line_3 = '42'
```

Comment: There is a lot of information here, but I don't have a clear idea of what the question is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks Snakecharmerb, I just want to update the session in one place by passing it to the base model.

Comment: And you can't because ...?